# Need to install some script/application that runs at startup - How?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-7, system-administration

I need to install some script/application that runs every time at startup and performs some operations under the user privileges. Can you please point me in the right direction?

My script would check whether the current version of certain .NET application (which runs **very slow** if not compiled, **very fast** if compiled) has been compiled. If negative, it would compile it (with `NGEN.EXE`). As we know the .NET apps must be compiled on a machine-by-machine basis.

This check must be performed every time the machine starts  up.

Comment: Do you by chance know why ngen makes your app so much faster? I haven't even bothered using it so far and we're running hard realtime applications without precompiling. So I really wonder why you need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple registry key for that:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Just add an arbitrarily named string value with the name of the script to run. There's also a corresponding key in HKCU, if you want to do it for certain users only.

Comment: Okay, that's a start! (literally :-) I guess that for further details like "How to determine whether a .NET application is compiled?", I should open another question...

Comment: I guess, yes. But see my comment above.